# What are "Super Cow Powers" and why doesn't my aptitude have them?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

```
sudo aptitude help
aptitude 0.4.11.11
Usage: aptitude [-S fname] [-u|-i]
   aptitude [options] <action> ...
  Actions (if none is specified, aptitude will enter interactive mode):

 ...

 This aptitude does not have Super Cow Powers.
```

Comment: sounds like a question for the history books - gave me a good laugh when I saw it :P

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I think it's referring to [`apt-get moo`](http://lwn.net/Articles/172231/):

```
$ apt-get moo  
         (__)  
         (oo)  
   /------\/  
  / |    ||  
 *  /\---/\  
    ~~   ~~  
...."Have you mooed today?"...
```

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(program)):

> *aptitude* states that, unlike [Advanced Packaging Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool), it "does not have Super Cow Powers". In apt-get "super cow powers" can be found by issuing the command `apt-get moo`. However, in aptitude issuing moo will give the user a prompt saying there are no easter eggs.
>
> However, by issuing `aptitude -v moo`, then `aptitude -vv moo`, and so on the user will see a series of statements telling them to go away, some ending with a picture not unlike the original apt-get easter egg. Different versions of the program have different sequences.

And, as [wRAR](https://superuser.com/users/10656/wrar) commented, the term “Super Cow Powers” is a direct quote from `apt-get --help`:

> This APT has Super Cow Powers.

Comment: haha, no easter eggs indeed.

Comment: yes, got to vote twice!

Comment: And "Super Cow Powers" is a quote from `apt-get --help`

Comment: It's a snake eating an elephant of course!

Comment: Doesn't really look like a hat to me ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Not so well known, but there is also `ip moo`:

```
 _ __ ___   ___   ___
| '_ ` _ \ / _ \ / _ \
| | | | | | (_) | (_) |
|_| |_| |_|\___/ \___/


P.S. no real cows were harmed for this moo
```

Cows have been hidden as easter eggs in [pinball games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinball).

Answer (score 6):

While inspecting around it ,just have a look at the easter-eggs

[image]

Comment: do `aptitude -vvvvvv moo`

Answer (score 2):

Please use this:

```
aptitude -v moo
aptitude -vvvvv moo
aptitude -vvvvvv moo
```

Comment: @Chenmunka Doesn't that mean aptitude do have Super Cow Powers?